# How to remove everything after http://example.com with awk or sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, url

Let's say I have an output file with a large quantity of URLs in it. How would I remove a part of the URL with awk or sed so that the final result would be `http://example.com` and not `http://example.com/folder/file.html`.

Comment: What does the input look like? one URL per line? delimited by spaces, pipes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
 sed 's#^\(https\?://\)\?\([^/]*\)/.*#\1\2#' filename
```

With this command and the following file,

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.html
https://example.com/foo/bar.html
example.com/foo/bar.html
```

the output will be

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
example.com
```

The way it works is as follows

- `\(https\?://\)\?` matches at most 1 occurence of either `http://` or `https://`. The parenthesis capture the match in `\1`
- `\([^/]*\)` matches anything after that until the next `/`, and the match is captured in `\2`
- `/.*` matches the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything after the first lone (not double) `/`:

```
sed -r 's#([^/])/[^/].*#\1#'
```

The expression `s#([^/])/[^/].*#\1#` will perform a substitution using the regular expression `([^/])/[^/].*`. This will match any character that is not a `/`, followed by a single `/` (and other characters to the end of the input line).

The substitution replaces the match with the character in front of the lone `/` (which otherwise would have been substituted away).

Testing it on the file

```
http://example.com/folder/file.html
http://example.bar.com/folder/file.html
http://example.com:8080/folder/file.html
```

```
$ sed -r 's#([^/])/[^/].*#\1#' file
http://example.com
http://example.bar.com
http://example.com:8080
```

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{ print $1 "//" $3 }' file
http://example.com
http://example.bar.com
http://example.com:8080
```

Here, I'm using `/` as a field delimiter, and then I'm simply picking out the first and thrid field and outputting them with the string `//` in-between.

Answer (score 0):

TO use `sed` to strip trailing parts of URLs, assuming they are one-per-line, or space-separated:

```
sed 's!\(http://[^/]*\)[^ ]*!\1!g' < input > output
```

This uses sed's search & replace functionality; the delimiters between the pattern, replacement, and flags is set to `!` here.

The pattern to match is:

- `http://` followed by anything except a forward-slash -- and this section of the pattern is captured in parenthesis as "group 1"
- (anything except a space), zero or more times -- this is the trailing part of the URL, specifically *not* captured in the parenthesis

The replacement is:

- the previously-captured "group 1"

The flags are:

- do this `g`lobally, meaning as many times per line as possible

Comment: Why would you need the global flag?

Comment: In case there were multiple URLs per line (not yet clarified by OP)

Answer (score 0):

For large files `grep` might get the job done pretty fast. Also easy to remember syntax.

```
grep -Eo '^https?://[^/]+' fname
```

Using `sed` doesn't require more than

```
sed -r 's|(https?://[^/]*).*|\1|' fname
```

or `cut` without using difficult regexes

```
cut -d'/' -f1,2,3 fname
```